# Windows Azure stored procedure not executing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure

My problem is as follows: I have a site that uses a handful of stored procedures and all of these work fine in my local development environment.

However one of these stored procedures is either not being fired or is failed once it has been published to Windows Azure.

My connection to the database is good as other parts of the site function correctly, I have used fiddler to check that the post event is passing through the correct data - which it is.

I have gone onto the Azure database and looked at the stored procedure and it all looks good, I have even tested it with the Azure tools - I can pass in data and it executes without an issue.

So I an stumped as to what else I can do to find what cause of this problem.

Last thing I did was double check my local copy and then republish this to Azure.

Stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 -- Insert statements for procedure here
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Events] ([Type] ,[StartDate]) VALUES (@Type, @StartDate)
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of this problem found - still to find fix.

The issue was not with the Store Procedure, as this was not being called due to a mismatch of cultures between input, site and finaly the DB.

In all my tests I was passing in UK date format (the proper way to use dates dd/mm/yyyy), this meant that my model was valid, however when deployed to azure (on EU server) the date format that it expects is US (not a proper way to use dates mm/dd/yyyy!)

So the following code was doing its job and redirecting me back to the current page.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    database.SaveNewEvent(model);
  }
return Redirect.....
```

Once I commented out this line of code I got the real error and can now look at changing the culture of my site and the database to use a real date format.

```
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

Thanks to everyone how helped me out with this one :)

Answer (score 0):

How sure are you that your stored procedure is not running? There are three possible outcomes: your code didn't call the proc, the proc ran but threw an error you are not catching, or the proc ran successfully.

Try running the following statement after you run your code to verify that the proc is not running. It is taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx). It won't show you the call to the proc, but it will show the statements called within it. Make sure you run this statement before and after your test. If you don't see the statements your proc is running, it's probably not being called. I would add a SELECT 0 at the top of your proc as a token to look for in the output below in case your INSERT statement fails (in which case it may not show up below).

```
SELECT query_stats.query_hash AS "Query Hash", 
    SUM(query_stats.total_worker_time) / SUM(query_stats.execution_count) AS "Avg CPU Time",
    MIN(query_stats.statement_text) AS "Statement Text"
FROM 
    (SELECT QS.*, 
    SUBSTRING(ST.text, (QS.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
    ((CASE statement_end_offset 
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(ST.text)
        ELSE QS.statement_end_offset END 
            - QS.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text
     FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS QS
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(QS.sql_handle) as ST) as query_stats
GROUP BY query_stats.query_hash
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the above and found the azure query performance - From all of this it looks like the store procedure is not being triggered. I am still non the wiser as to why - it does work localy

Comment: Then you need to look at your code. Are you connecting to the correct database? If you don't specify a database name, your code will connect to master. Are you trapping all exceptions? Are you logging your exceptions somewhere for review?

Comment: I'm connecting to the correct database as other store procedures use the same database connection service i have created and these work. I am using Log4Net to trap any errors executing this service and nothing is being spat out (will look at this further).